# Multiplas App Laravel utilizando a mesma tabela de jobs

Tags: php, laravel

Possuo em meu cenário 3 servidores `http` rodando a mesma aplicação `Laravel` e compartilhando a mesma Database, onde o primeiro servidor realiza o `LoadBalance` utilizando `nginx`, basicamente com o mesmo peso de carga.

A aplicação trabalha com diversas filas de jobs utilizando o drive database na tabela "jobs".
O único servidor que processa os `jobs` (`php artisan queue:listen`) é o app1.

Gostaria de saber se há alguma contra-indicação sobre processar os `jobs` também nos outros servidores e se alguém já teve alguma experiencia parecida.

Answer (score -2):

Desde que o balanceamento esteja adequado, não vejo problemas.

Acredito que você deveria fazer uma análise comparativa:

- Se eu executar uma única aplicação em um único servidor de filas, e esta aplicação/servidor suportar, digamos, 10K (dez mil) filas hora ... comparando com três aplicações executando um único servidor de filas, o volume é o mesmo? Então não há contraindicação
- Já, a possibilidade de usar conexões diferentes para filas diferentes é justamente para que você possa balancear corretamente, novamente digamos, se as três aplicações executarem 2k filas, e uma única executar 30k filas, é mais provável que seja necessário balancear com execução de filas em conexões/servidores diferentes para esta única aplicação ao contrário das três citadas.

Espero ter sido claro que a questão avaliativa aqui é a demanda/volume de execução de jobs e o custo computacional (processamento+memória) exigido por cada job, para realmente identificar se existe uma contraindicação, como você citou, em executar filas de vários sistemas em um único servidor/conexão.

Para quem necessitar de mais entendimento em como configurar conexões diferentes para filas de execução em Laravel, acessar a seção da [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#customizing-the-queue-and-connection)